# Element doesn't show in inspect element when using document.write

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, inspect-element

I wrote the following JS code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.write("<img src=x>")
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

while my function works fine and adds a new img tag to the page whenever I use Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome then Ctrl+F then I type `<img src=x>` and I get `0 of 0 found`. How to fix this?

Comment: *"...and search for the result () it shows 0..."* How are you searching? (Inspect element should take you right to it.) What's showing 0?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ctrl+shift+i in chrome then ctrl+F then I type <img src=x> and I get 0 of 0 found

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> ctrl+shift+i in chrome then ctrl+F then I type  and I get 0 of 0 found

There's no need to do that. Just right-click the image and click Inspect. Chrome will take you right to it in the Elements panel.

Re searching in the Elements panel:

The Elements panel doesn't show the exact HTML you wrote, it shows you the DOM, rendered as canonical HTML. So for instance, the `src` attribute will be in quotes.

**But**, the search box in the Elements panel doesn't search *HTML*, it searches the DOM. So typing plain text will match text in text in text nodes, text in attributes, attribute names, tag names, etc., but not exact HTML. So if you search for the URL of the image, it'll find it, but it won't find it if you search for `<img src=`. This has nothing to do with it having been added via `document.write`, it's just how Chrome's Elements panel works.

You can find the element by typing XPath or a CSS selector, for instance `img[src=x]` will find it. Here's an example (I used your Gravatar rather than `x`):

[image: Example using search in elements panel]

There, you can see that the selector `img[src*=gravatar]` found the image, because that selector (using the "contains" attribute selector, `*=`) matches the element.